# Parsing of revisions involving insertion of dollar signs

Tags: bug, editing

Extremely niche thing here that hardly affects anyone at all, but seems worth reporting to someone.

I was reviewing a suggested edit (number 3 in the [revision history](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/67765/revisions)) in side-by-side mode. One of the fixes had changed the source from something like

> $x = 3$ and $y = 5$

to

> $$x = 3$$ and $$y = 5$$

The side-by-side display seems to miss the second and third `$$` symbols, concatenating both equations and the `and` into a single equation, which makes it somewhat difficult to see what the change is doing. At first glance it looks like the edit ruined everything.

A more dramatic effect can be seen in the second revision, where the side-by-side display thinks entire sentences are inside math mode and so makes everything look like line noise.

I understand that this display mode is trying to strike a tricky balance between displaying changes in source and showing things as formatted where possible, but in cases like this, it doesn't help at all in the review process. Is there any fix for the parsing so that the segregation between text and math is respected?

Comment: There are several ways that MathJax and the visual differ don't get along. Probably this is bothering people on other MathJax equipped sites.

Comment: I've had issues with this too (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128068/mathjax-not-loaded-properly-on-review). I don't see prospects of this being fixed; however if a side-by-side view _without_ coloring was implemented, that could help things significantly.

Comment: Irritatingly, the MathJax renderer runs on the *Markdown* diff if that's your default, making this even harder to parse. The work-around is to load with the visual diff selected and then switch to Markdown diff. cc @Manish

Comment: @Shog9 Huh, nice idea. However, that shouldn't be happening in the first place; the MD diff has the class [`tex2jax_ignore`](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.1-latest/options/tex2jax.html), which is supposed to denote "leave this alone" blocks. And MathJax _is_ configured to ignore the `tex2jax_ignore` and `dno` classes.